# How to write onclick for a button to use script on a particular page

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, dom-events

I need to print PDF in current window but it uses script in another PHP page.

```
<a href="PostalPdf.php?address_id=<?php echo $row['UserId']?>" class="btn 
 btn-sm green"> pdf<i class="fa fa-medkit"></i></a>
```

And script for generating PDF is present in PostalPdf.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function PrintDiv() {    
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=750,height=300');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
</script>
```

How can I use above script ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you elaborate on the exact situation and what the expected result is? I'd like to help.